# Error 80004005 when executing query in ADODB (VBA, Excel and Access 2010)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, inner-join, adodb

I have a problem which I can not get my head around. I have an Access database where I am trying to create a set of queries in by using VBA in Excel by use of ADODB.

I have several queries that are successfully created, ie. the one below here. The second will however not work. If I copy the query manually to the access database (From SELECT and forward) and save is as "DK_Teledata_1" it works perfect

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DK_Aktiviteter_Union_1 AS SELECT DK_Aktivitet.År FROM DK_Aktivitet;
```

And the one that does not work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DK_Teledata_1 AS SELECT DK_Teledata.Dato FROM DK_Teledata INNER JOIN Time_Intervals ON DK_Teledata.Interval = Time_Intervals.Time_Interval;
```

The following queries with the same data are created without any problems:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DK_Teledata_1 AS SELECT * FROM DK_Teledata;
CREATE PROCEDURE DK_Teledata_1 AS SELECT * FROM Time_Intervals;
CREATE PROCEDURE DK_Teledata_1 AS SELECT * FROM Time_Intervals, DK_Teledata;
```

As soon as I create the join or use a "WHERE DK_Teledata.Interval = Time_Intervals.Time_Interval" it fails.

The fields Intervals and Time_Intervals are both Text fields with the same length and properties.

Using Excel 2010, accdb database file and "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a wild guess, I'll suggest you substitute `CREATE VIEW` for `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

If that also doesn't work, you can use DAO to create your query.

```vb
Dim strSql As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

strSql = "SELECT DK_Teledata.Dato" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM DK_Teledata INNER JOIN Time_Intervals" & vbCrLf & _
    "ON DK_Teledata.Interval = Time_Intervals.Time_Interval;"
Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\db_folder\your.accdb", True, False)
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("DK_Teledata_1", strSql)
```

That code uses early binding so requires setting a reference.  But you could do the same thing with late binding which doesn't require a reference.

```
Dim strSql As String
Dim dbe As Object
Dim db As Object
Dim qdf As Object

strSql = "SELECT DK_Teledata.Dato" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM DK_Teledata INNER JOIN Time_Intervals" & vbCrLf & _
    "ON DK_Teledata.Interval = Time_Intervals.Time_Interval;"
Set dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
Set db = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\db_folder\your.accdb", True, False)
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("DK_Teledata_1", strSql)
```

Comment: I still have not found a reason why the adodb connection did not work. But after changing the connection to a DAO connection, it did the job! Thank you very much for the help

Comment: The reason: Access databases run on Jet, not the ANSI-Standard SQL you're used to, and 'CREATE VIEW' and 'PROCEDURE' aren't available in Jet SQL - neither DAO nor ADODB will run SQL statements on a database engine that can't read them. @HansUp's answer works because the **DAO object** is running the 'CreateQueryDef' method on the Database object instantiated from your Access database: you're bypassing SQL altogether. Meanwhile, 80004005 is the default COM object error: it means the developer who wrote the ADODB object didn't bother to write any of this into into an informative error message

Comment: @Nile `CREATE VIEW` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` are both supported under ADO/OleDb.  Indeed Martin reported several `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements which worked.

Comment: @HansUp - ADO supports whatever the database engine and its SQL dialect supports: and JET SQL does not support `CREATE VIEW` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` - **however, this does not appear to be the whole story**: I have a report from another source that the latest versions of the OLEDB driver (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) will indeed run those commands: the driver appears to be parsing or translating the SQL and feeding a 'create querydef' command (or undocumented Jet-SQL keywords)  to the Jet database engine. This isn't available to those of use who are still using the JET OLEDB 4.0 drivers.